# Does someone know how to specify "partial matches" in my command, instead of "complete matches" ? Cygwin, Windows

Tags: file, sed, grep, duplicates, cygwin

I have been trying to find the solution for weeks, I did read at least 50+ topics here and elsewhere, none working in my case. ChatGPT couldn't help neither. I'm using Cygwin last version (3.4) on Windows :

File 1 : "remove.txt"

```
Word
Sentence
Number
```

File 2 : "input.txt"

```
Word1
College
Sentence
Number.day
School
```

File 3 : "output.txt"  = result file I need :

```
College
School
```

Currently, I use :

```
while read pattern; do
  grep -vF "$pattern" input.txt > output.txt && mv output.txt input.txt;
done < remove.txt
```

However, it only removes the word `Sentence` in the above example because it's a complete match. For some reason, it can't remove partial matches, which I need.

I also tried many solutions using sed, but couldn't do anything ; they were working if the `remove.txt` file had only 1 word, in 1 line, but in my case many patterns to be removed (many words, each one in different lines), and it didn't work if >1 line of patterns.
The command above is the one that was closer to work, but only with complete matches.

Thank you so much!

Think I explained everything above.

---------------------------------------------------------- EDIT :

I am currently using :
grep -vf remove.txt input.txt > output.txt

"remove.txt" contains :

```
Word
Sentence
Number
```

"output.txt" result with :

```
Word1
College
School
```

"Word1" should have been removed, but for some reasons with this command Cygwin is not able to remove all the patterns. It did remove "Sentence" and "Number.day".

However - update - When the pattern "Word" in the remove.txt file is on the last line (3rd line), it removes "Word1" from the input file. But when "Word" is on the 1st or 2nd line of the remove.txt file, it simply doesn't remove the pattern.

To make it more clear --------

When "remove.txt" contains :

```
Sentence
Number
Word
```

The output.txt file ends up with (this time "Number.day" isn't being removed) :

```
College
Number.day
School
```

---

And when "remove.txt" contains Word at the start of the file :

```
Word
Sentence
Number
```

The output.txt file is :

```
Word1
College
School
```

Can't seem to figure out why the command doesn't loop all patterns 1 by 1 and remove them all, if matches partly, but only removes 1 depending on the order in the "remove.txt" file.

Comment: You use `grep`s `-F` option so you can't expect `Word` to match `Word1` and `Number` to match `Number.day`, right? `-F` is for fixed strings, not regular expressions.

Comment: You are right. However now, even with -vF or -v in the command, the output.txt file is exactly as the input.txt one. I can't even reproduce the first progress I did, for a reason I don't know. I'm in the right folder location, with the right file names, nothing changed, but the patterns (part or complete matches) aren't getting removed anymore at all. I don't know what I'm doing wrong..    I am trying "grep -v -f remove.txt input.txt > output.txt"  and it is able to remove 1 occurence only (the first one)

Comment: Can you rewrite your `remove.txt` to include appropriate reg-ex chars? `Word[0-9]*` maybe? Good luck.

Comment: It could be a problem with Windows line endingings. What's the content of `remove.txt` when you are **not** using `-F` ?

Comment: It's impossible to see properly here in the comments. Please update your question with the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

A shell script one-liner can do this:

```
cat remove.txt | xargs -I % sed -i '/%/d' input.txt
```

The **"-I"** flag of the *xargs* command will make the following symbol (%) a string holder to store the incoming arguments from the previous command "cat remove.txt".

You can put a "-t" flag for xargs to see the verbose output of the xargs. In this case, the outputs are

```
 sed -i /Word/d input.txt
 sed -i /Sentence/d input.txt
 sed -i /Number/d input.txt
```

The *sed* command use **"-i"** to perform the same file modification so we can output the result to the same input file (input.txt). The **'/%/d'** command of sed will match the incoming string from remove.txt and remove the matching string in input.txt.

If you wish to remove the matched word instead the entire line. You can modify the sed command from **'/%/d'** into **'s/%[0-9a-zA-Z.]*//g'**

I hope this can help :)